# Can't set androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar to androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In my android project:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

I wanto to set toolbar in `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`

but in line:

```
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

I get compile error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'setSupportActionBar(androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar)'
```

I can't extend `MainFragmentActivity`  from `AppCompatActivity`

I have no source code of `MainFragmentActivity`

Comment: well, it's becuase this class has no such method ...

Comment: How I can set toolbar to my activity

Comment: *I can't extend MainFragmentActivity from AppCompatActivity* use `AppCompatDelegate`

Answer (score 1):

FragmentActivity does not have `setSupportActionBar` method

if you really need `actionBar` then try to extend `AppCompactActivity`

like following

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

Comment: I can't do this. I has no source code of MainFragmentActivity

Comment: The best thing you can do is use your own class in its place, then.

Comment: How you are going to set ToolBar then, if you do not have the source code